# JMeter Parameter Passing in CLI mode is not working with -r (remote) switch

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to pass the Thread count parameter to JMeter in CLI mode. This works perfectly well when the script is running locally. I need to run the script remotely, so I am using the -r switch so that the JMeter script runs on the configured remote clients.

This is my cli command:

```
jmeter -n -t "C:\ScriptLocation\Sanity_WebV2_Prod.jmx" -r -l c:\CSV\log.jtl -Jusers=4
```

The intention is that the above command should run the script on remote machine for 4 users (threads). Number of Threads in the thread properties is set to `${__P(users)}`.

But the script is actually running only for 1 user (the default values) not for 4 users that is passed as the parameter.

When executed the above mentioned cli command `w/o -r` switch i.e script executing on the Local machine it is working perfectly fine i.e for 4 users.

Need help in solving this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Try to use `-Gusers` option instead of `-Jusers` one:

```
-D[prop_name]=[value] - defines a java system property value.
-J[prop name]=[value] - defines a local JMeter property.
-G[prop name]=[value] - defines a JMeter property to be sent to all remote servers.
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, I was just having the exact same issue and this worked for me; can any moderator take action? seems like @PayalSinha is not active here.

Comment: is it possible to send different values to each of the remote servers?

Comment: Agree with @CarlosMelo . This should be the accepted answer, worked for me too.